# Insert long set of values in one row

Tags: sql, postgresql, excel, vba

Is there another way to insert row (set of values) into table ?

I don't like that I have to write long sql insert query that perhaps will change.
Set of values is quite long, so perhaps there is another way.

```
Insert into myTable values (val1, val2, ... val100);
```

Answering qustions:
I have VBA class object - let's say row. I don't want to do it with external files. It has to be direct call:

Public Sub RunQuery(query As String)

```
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset

    Set dbs = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")

    dbs.Open getConnectionString
    rst.Open query, dbs

    Set rst = Nothing
    dbs.Close

End Sub
```

This works fine, but long sets of values are pain.

Comment: `copy table from  csv`

Comment: You want to insert an entire Excel row into a table?  An Access table is capable of housing 255 fields.  An Excel worksheet has 16,384 columns.

Comment: ...also, if the concern is that the source data is going to change then how would you like the application to "know" what goes where? Perhaps you need to write some VBA code to dynamically figure out what goes where.  Might be more of a pain for you.

Comment: other modules make sure data for insert is ok. Now its just a nicer way of writing code, playing with objects or maybe Posgresql only accepsts only 1 syntax...

Answer (score 1):

If your other modules make sure data for insert is ok and you just want save time instead of typing all the time `Insert into myTable values (val1, val2, ... val100);` maybe this UDF can help you save some time. This UDF will return a string with all values from selected cells concatenated.

Please, note this only works if the range selected is in the same row.

```
Public Function CREATE_SQL_QUERY(ByRef FromThisRange As Range) As String
Dim i As Byte

Dim MyRanges() As Variant
MyRanges = FromThisRange.Value

For i = 1 To FromThisRange.Count Step 1
    If i = 1 Then
        CREATE_SQL_QUERY = MyRanges(1, i)
    Else
        CREATE_SQL_QUERY = CREATE_SQL_QUERY & ", " & MyRanges(1, i)
    End If
Next i

CREATE_SQL_QUERY = "(" & CREATE_SQL_QUERY & ");"
End Function
```

I tested it with 13 cells, each one of them containing `Value1, Value 2...` and so on, and this function returned `(Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4, Value5, Value6, Value7, Value8, Value9, Value10, Value11, Value12, Value13);`